# Is it possible to download the first few frames from a Video URL and than use that to create the Thumbnail image?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, url, video, thumbnails

I am currently using the below code to make a thumbnail image from my videos to populate the cell.image in a tableview. However some of the videos are too long and waiting to download the whole video is too user unfriendly. Is it possible to only download the first 1 second of a video and still have the ability to use the below code. Will the url be corrupted by Not downloading the whole video ?

```
 -(void)addThumbNailImagesToMutableArray :(NSURL *)url
{
    AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL: url options:nil];
    AVAssetImageGenerator *generator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
    NSError *err = NULL;
    CMTime requestedTime = CMTimeMake(1,30);     // To create thumbnail image
    CGImageRef imgRef = [generator copyCGImageAtTime:requestedTime actualTime:NULL error:&err];
       NSLog(@"err = %@, imageRef = %@", err, imgRef);

    if (imgRef != NULL) {
        _thumbnailImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:imgRef];
        CGImageRelease(imgRef);    // MUST release explicitly to avoid memory leak
        _thumbNailImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(_thumbnailImage);
        [_thumbNailArray addObject:_thumbNailImageData];

    } else {

        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"smallPlaceHolder.jpg"];
        _thumbNailImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img);
        [_thumbNailArray addObject:_thumbNailImageData];

    }
}
```